# How to properly create a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a dictionary in a function but I don't know for which reason I got this:

```
MONdic = {"mama"}
print MONdic
```

What I get as a result is :

`set(['mama'])`

Any help ?

Comment: Dictionary should contains key value pairs.

Comment: Check this : https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/how-to-use-dictionaries-in-python/

Comment: Hey @Marwa please figure this out for yourself it's for your own good and it's quite easy.

Comment: Basicly a dict is a set of keys that reference to values. Thus the `{}` construstor is used for both dicts and sets. The difference is that a set is a collection of unique values and a dict is a collection of uniqu keys and arbutrary values. The empty curly braces, `{key: value}`, `dict(key=value)` and others will return a dict and `{value1, value2}` will return a set.

Comment: Because MONdic is dictionary object so , https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you pass an element or list of elements to `{}`, it will create a **set**.

But if you try passing `key value pairs` to `{}`, it will create a dictionary.

`MONdic = {"key":"value"}`, then the value of `MONdic` will be `{"key":"value"}`

Answer (score 2):

dict is based on key value pairs (You have created a set)

```
d = {'key':'val'}
```

Answer (score 0):

dictionary must has keys and values
like:
`my_dict =  {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}`

check https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp
for accessing it, changing values, loop it ..

Answer (score 0):

But the problem is that I have a second dictionary that should merge with MONdic as in this example:

```
for key, value in results.items():
    MONdic[key].extend(value)
```

To be able to merge these two dictionaries, they need to have the same keys. The values of MONdic should be empty in the beginning and I don't want to receive these kind of results if I do so :

```
MONdic = {"mama":[]}
for key, value in results.items():
    MONdic[key].extend(value)

>>>> {"mama":[[1,2,5,9]]}
```